# Unrecognized option: --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED al intentar ejecutar StartSonar.bat de Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

Tengo la versión java 8. Cuando le doy al `StartSonar.bat` me aparece esto:

```
C:\SonarQube\sonarqube-9.1.0.47736\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Unrecognized option: --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Comment: ¿Revisaste los [prerrequisitos para la versión 9.1](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/)?

Comment: Especialmente donde dice: *"The SonarQube scanners and the SonarQube server **require Java version 11"***.

Comment: Ahh ok, pense que se podian con otras versiones. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

**SonarQube necesita que tu pc tenga instalado Java SE 11** para poder levantar el servidor localmente.

Dejo [en este enlace](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/) la documentación oficial dónde se específica, y [en este otro enlace](https://www.oracle.com/es/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html) el link para poder descargar esta versión desde el website oficial de oracle.